# multiple label/input and label/select don't align/appear using css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align rows of label/input and label/select combinations but nothing appears after the first label/select row.

```css
#form {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  height: 900px;
  width: 500px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: 35px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}
error {
  color: #FF0000;
  font-size: 80%
}
body {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  color: darkblue;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 90%;
}
h2 {
  color: DarkOliveGreen;
}
label.text-label {
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: darkblue;
  height: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  text-align: right;
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
label.select-label {
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: darkblue;
  height: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  text-align: right;
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
input {
  height: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin-top: 10px;
  float: left;
}
select {
  height: 25px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin-top: 10px;
  float: left;
}
input[type=button] {
  float: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="form">
  <h2>Employee/Consultant Manager</h2>
  <form action="" method="post" name="registration" class="register">

    <fieldset>
      <label for="first" class="text-label">First Name:</label>
      <input name="first" />
      <label for="middle" class="text-label">Middle Name:</label>
      <input name="middle" />
      <label for="last" class="text-label">Last Name:</label>
      <input name="last" />
      <label for="email" class="text-label">Manager Email:</label>
      <input name="eEmail" />
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title" class="select-label">Title:</label>
        <select name="title" id="title" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="department" class="select-label">Department:</label>
        <select name="department" id="department" />
      </div>
      <input name="regbutton" type="button" class="button" value="Register" />
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code looks fine to me - https://jsfiddle.net/91pfst8q/

Comment: Snippet works for me (Safari 9)

Comment: I can reproduce it in chrome/windows, cuts off after the first select

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Run it through a validator to check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close the select tags for all of them to appear:

https://jsfiddle.net/x7fc3rLg/

```
<div id="form">
<h2>Employee/Consultant Manager</h2>
    <form action="" method="post" name="registration" class="register">

            <fieldset> 
            <label for="first" class="text-label">First Name:</label>
            <input name="first" />
            <label for="middle" class="text-label">Middle Name:</label>
            <input name="middle" />
            <label for="last" class="text-label">Last Name:</label>
            <input name="last" />
            <label for="email" class="text-label">Manager Email:</label>
            <input name="eEmail" />
                    <div class="form-group">
            <label for="title" class="select-label">Title:</label>
            <select name="title" id="title"/></select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
            <label for="department" class="select-label">Department:</label>
            <select name="department"  id="department" /></select>
                    </div>
            <input name="regbutton" type="button" class="button" value="Register" />
        </fieldset> 
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Closing the select tags fixes the problem on my browser (though it seems to work as is for others).

```css
#form {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  height: 900px;
  width: 500px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: 35px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}
error {
  color: #FF0000;
  font-size: 80%
}
body {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  color: darkblue;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 90%;
}
h2 {
  color: DarkOliveGreen;
}
label.text-label {
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: darkblue;
  height: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  text-align: right;
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
label.select-label {
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: darkblue;
  height: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  text-align: right;
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
input {
  height: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin-top: 10px;
  float: left;
}
select {
  height: 25px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin-top: 10px;
  float: left;
}
input[type=button] {
  float: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="form">
  <h2>Employee/Consultant Manager</h2>
  <form action="" method="post" name="registration" class="register">

    <fieldset>
      <label for="first" class="text-label">First Name:</label>
      <input name="first" />
      <label for="middle" class="text-label">Middle Name:</label>
      <input name="middle" />
      <label for="last" class="text-label">Last Name:</label>
      <input name="last" />
      <label for="email" class="text-label">Manager Email:</label>
      <input name="eEmail" />
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title" class="select-label">Title:</label>
        <select name="title" id="title" ></select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="department" class="select-label">Department:</label>
        <select name="department" id="department" ></select>
      </div>
      <input name="regbutton" type="button" class="button" value="Register" />
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I missed closing the select and appreciate those that pointed this out.  Thanks again.